# How to find the available numbers of Fully used LUT-FF pairs in xilinx vivado?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I am new to verilog-hdl design. I am using xilinx vivado in order to synthesize and implement the design. The design basically a FFT algorithm. I want to calculate the percentage of "Fully used LUT-FF pairs" used by the design. After implementation by selecting a FPGA device the total Fully used LUT-FF pairs consumed is coming out as 162. I have attached the report. I did not find the total no. of available Fully used LUT-FF pairs. From the report can I find the total no. of Fully used LUT-FF pairs present in that FPGA device or where could I find it?[image]

Comment: you should remove vrilog and system-verilog tags. they have nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a little bit of math to get the value you are looking for.   The total available LUT FF pairs in your report is given as 254200. The value of 162 represents fully used LUT FF pairs.  You could say that 254200 - 162 represents the unused AND Non-fully used LUT FF pairs available.  The 502 in that report you can take as a comparable value so you could say 502 LUT FF's have been used (either fully or partially) out of the 254200, so 254200-502 means that there are 253698 FULLY available LUT FF's